# Zodiacal sign python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
from datetime import date
def program():
Year = input("year of birth:" )
Month = input("month of birth:" )
Day = input("day of birth:" )
Date_of_Birth = (Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year)
print('Your Date of Birth is ' + Date_of_Birth)
d = date.today()
y = d.year
os.system("cls")
age = y - int(Year)
print('Your age is ' + str(age))



def zodiac_sign():
    if (int(Month)==12<2):
         print("\n Capricorn")
    elif (int(Month)==1<3):
        print("\n aquarium")
    elif (int(Month)==2<4):
        print("\n Pices")
    elif(int(Month)==3<5):
        print ("\n Aries")
    elif(int(Month)==4<6):
        print("\n Taurus")
    elif(int(Month)==5<7):
        print("\n Gemini")
    elif(int(Month)==6<8):
        print("\n cancer")
    elif(int(Month)==7<9): 
        print ("\n leo")
    elif(int(Month)==8<9): 
        print ("\n virgo")
    elif(int(Month)==9<10):
        print ("\n libra")
    elif(int(Month)==10<12): 
        print ("\n Scorpio")
    elif(int(Month)==11<13):
        print("\n Sagittarius")
zodiac_sign()

input()
program()
```

I'm trying to get the zodiac sign but I can't find a way to insert the number. I already tried to put it like this:

```
if (int(Month)==12<2 , int(day)==22<1):
   print("\n Capricorn")
```

etc etc

but it keeps saying "capricorn"  no matter which date I put in. Can you give me any solution?

I'm using python V3.4.0

Comment: Not sure what you expect `int(Month)==12<2` to do, but it doesn't make much sense. It's equivalent to `(int(Month)==12) < 2`; the left operand is either `True` or `False`, and you compare it to `2`. Step back and re-think what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
from datetime import date
def program():
    Year = input("year of birth:" )
    Month = input("month of birth:" )
    Day = input("day of birth:" )
    Date_of_Birth = (Day + "/" + Month + "/" + Year)
    print('Your Date of Birth is ' + Date_of_Birth)
    d = date.today()
    y = d.year
    os.system("cls")
    age = y - int(Year)
    print('Your age is ' + str(age))

    if ((int(Month)==12 and int(Day) >= 22)or(int(Month)==1 and int(Day)<= 19)):
        Signo_Zodiacal = ("\n Capricorn")
    elif ((int(Month)==1 and int(Day) >= 20)or(int(Month)==2 and int(Day)<= 17)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n aquarium")
    elif ((int(Month)==2 and int(Day) >= 18)or(int(Month)==3 and int(Day)<= 19)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Pices")
    elif ((int(Month)==3 and int(Day) >= 20)or(int(Month)==4 and int(Day)<= 19)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Aries")
    elif ((int(Month)==4 and int(Day) >= 20)or(int(Month)==5 and int(Day)<= 20)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Taurus")
    elif ((int(Month)==5 and int(Day) >= 21)or(int(Month)==6 and int(Day)<= 20)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Gemini")
    elif ((int(Month)==6 and int(Day) >= 21)or(int(Month)==7 and int(Day)<= 22)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Cancer")
    elif ((int(Month)==7 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==8 and int(Day)<= 22)): 
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Leo")
    elif ((int(Month)==8 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==9 and int(Day)<= 22)): 
            Signo_Zodiacal = ("\n Virgo")
    elif ((int(Month)==9 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==10 and int(Day)<= 22)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Libra")
    elif ((int(Month)==10 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==11 and int(Day)<= 21)): 
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Scorpio")
    elif ((int(Month)==11 and int(Day) >= 22)or(int(Month)==12 and int(Day)<= 21)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Sagittarius")

    print(zodiac_sign)

program()
```

fixed by me

Comment: some lines set "Signo_Zodiacal", some set "zodiac_sign". Too much code duplication.

Comment: You misspelled Aquarius

Answer (score 0):

```
  def again():
    print("")
    print("Please check you month")
    print("Month must be the following")
    print("01 - January")
    print("02 - Febuary")
    print("03 - March")
    print("04 - April")
    print("05 - May")
    print("06 - Jun")
    print("07 - Jully")
    print("08 - August")
    print("09 - September")
    print("10 - October")
    print("11 - Novemver")
    print("12 - December")
    print("")
def zodiac():
    month = input("Month of birth(eg. 01,04,,12):")
    day = int(input("Day of birth:"))
    bday = ( month + "/" + str(day))
    if (int(month) > 12):
        again()
        zodiac()
    elif month == "01":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()            
        elif (day <= 20):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Capricorn!")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Aquarius")
    elif month == "02":
        if (day >28):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 18):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Aquarius")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Pisces")
    elif month == "03":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 20):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Pisces")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Aries")
    elif month == "04":
        if (day > 30):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 20):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Aries")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Taurus")
    elif month == "05":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 20):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Taurus")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Gemini")
    elif month == "06":
        if (day > 30):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 21):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Gemini")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Cancer")
    elif month == "07":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 22):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Cancer")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Leo")
    elif month == "08":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <=23):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Leo")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Virgo")
    elif month == "09":
        if (day > 30):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 23):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Virgo")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Libra")
    elif month == "10":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 23):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Libra")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Scorpio")
    elif month == "11":
        if (day > 30):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 23):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Scorpio")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Sagittarius")
    elif month == "12":
        if (day > 31):
            print("")
            print("Invalid Date")
            print("Please try again!")
            print("")
            zodiac()
        elif (day <= 21):
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Sagittarius")
        else:
            print("Your Birthday is(mm/dd):",bday)
            print("Then your zodiac sign is Capricorn")
    else:
        print("")
        again()
        zodiac()
zodiac()
print("")
again = input("Type 'zodiac' if you want to try again: ")
if (again == "zodiac"):
    zodiac()
```

Comment: It would be great to add some explanation.